# How would you use Hashicorp's Nomad 'template stanza' to generate an nginx config file through the Nomad job file?

Tags: nginx, docker, consul, consul-template, nomad

With the assumption that Consul and Nomad has been configured to run on a pool of resource. How would you rendered a template file for the sole purpose of generating e.g. an Nginx 'default.conf' file.

Using the template stanza configuration below, as an example; Nomad fails to generate a default.conf 'file'; instead a default.conf 'directory' is created.

```
template {
    source        = "/path/to/tmp.ctmpl"
    destination   = "folder/default.conf"
    change_mode   = "restart"
    change_signal = "SIGINT"
}
```

I'm either missing a trick, or have misunderstood the functionalities of the 'template stanza'.

One of the issue with the template generating a directory rather than a file is, you cannot mount a directory to a config file path. So running a task that uses the Nomad docker driver with the exemplar 'docker' volume config results in an error.

```
volumes = ["/path/to/job/folder/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" ]
```

Or is it impossible to have the template stanza generate a config file?

*P.s. Using Nomad build 0.5.5**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just put together a little Nomad job showing this working, so you may have a slight configuration error. To allow you to run the job yourself I have made it available as a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/dadgar/2dcf68ab5c49f7a36dcfe74171ca7936). In the same gist I have a nginx.conf that has nginx listen on whatever port is in the Nomad job file.

Here is the Nomad job:

```
job "nginx" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"]
  type = "service"
  group "cache" {
    count = 1
    task "redis" {
      driver = "docker"
      config {
        image = "nginx:1.11.10"
        volumes = ["new/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" ]
        network_mode = "host"
      }

      artifact {
        source = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dadgar/2dcf68ab5c49f7a36dcfe74171ca7936/raw/c287c16dbc9ddc16b18fa5c65a37ff25d2e0e667/nginx.conf"
      }

      template {
        source        = "local/nginx.conf"
        destination   = "new/default.conf"
        change_mode   = "restart"
      }

      resources {
        network {
          mbits = 10
          port "nginx" {
            static = 8080
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can then query that address and see that nginx is bound to that port, thus the template being mounted is working properly.

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you take a look at the gist, I show the file being rendered and mounted properly as well.

Hope this helps you! Also be sure to check out the [community page](https://www.nomadproject.io/community.html) for getting help. We have both a Gitter room and a mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for the example, it works as expected.  Also,  good point, i'll check out the gitter room for future enquires.

Answer (score 2):

It is much easier to just put the configuration generated in either `local` or `secrets` folders in the working directory of the job (alloc directory). These folders will be available in the container as /secrets and /local. No volume mounts required.

Comment: How does one do that though? Putting the configuration inside `local`? I have the configuration file alongside my `.nomad` file.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up following the above solution based on the following error:

"Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type"

The following snippet it is how I made work nginx as a reverse proxy for my jenkins instance ( all nomad based ). This template is part of a multitasks job, made of a jenkins and an nginx one.

Hopefully it will be of some use to someone else in the same situation I was, for the last couple of days.

```
task "nginx" {

  driver = "docker"

  resources {
    cpu    = 75 
    memory = 75
  }   

  service {
    name = "jenkins-nginx"
    tags = ["urlprefix-/jenkins-nginx"]
    port = "http" 
    check {
      name     = "nginx port alive"
      type     = "http"
      path     = "/login"
      interval = "10s"
      timeout  = "2s"
    }   
  }   

      template {
        change_mode     = "restart"
        destination     = "local/default.conf"
        data = <<EOH
    upstream jenkins {
      server {{ env "NOMAD_ADDR_jenkins" }}; 
    }   
    server {
        listen {{ env "NOMAD_PORT_http" }}; 

        location / { 
               proxy_redirect              off;
               proxy_pass_header           Server;
               proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
               proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
               proxy_set_header            Host $http_host;
               proxy_set_header            X-NginX-Proxy true;
               proxy_set_header            X-Accel-Buffering no; 
               proxy_connect_timeout       5;  
               proxy_http_version          1.1;
               proxy_read_timeout          240;
               proxy_intercept_errors      on; 
               keepalive_timeout           3600;
               proxy_set_header Connection ''; 
               chunked_transfer_encoding   off;
               proxy_buffering             off;
               proxy_cache                 off;
               proxy_pass                  http://jenkins;
        }   
    }   
EOH
      }   

      config {
        image = "nginx"

        network_mode = "host"
        ports = ["http","https"]

        volumes = [ "local/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" ]
      }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply use this job :

```
job "nginx" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"]
  type = "service"
  group "cache" {
    count = 1
    task "redis" {
      template {
        change_mode = "noop"
        destination = "local/default.conf"
        data = <<EOH
server {
    listen       {{ env "NOMAD_PORT_nginx" }};
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
EOH
      }
      driver = "docker"
      config {
        image = "nginx:1.11.10"
        volumes = ["local/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf" ]
        network_mode = "host"
      }

      resources {
        network {
          mbits = 10
          port "nginx" {
            static = 8080
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```